# Starting <div> inside 2nd li from the 1st li

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I have a problem with `<div>` which is inside 2nd `<li>`

I would like to show it on the 1st column.
Currently I have something like this:
[image]

I would like to move it:

[image]

Please see attached code below:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            li {
                list-style-type: none;
                float:left;
                width: 20%;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
<body>
<ul>
<li>
    <p>Test</p>
</li>
<li>
    <p>Test</p>
    <div>
        <p>Test2</p>
    </div>
</li>
<li>
    <p>Test</p>
</li>
</body>
</html>
```

Please see all code here: http://jsfiddle.net/hcj1Lb03/1/.
Unfortunately, I can't just cut and paste it on the 1st li.

How can I move the `<div>` element with styling?

Comment: Define "a problem" please. What are you trying to do? And post a complete code example in your question. We should not be expected to visit a third party site to see your code.

Comment: Positioning *could* do it but it wouldn't be very flexible. I'd be using JS to snip it out and move it.

Comment: what is your expected op?

Comment: @j08691 I detailed my problem.

Comment: Then instead of placing div content in 2 nd li, place it in new li after 3rd like this http://jsfiddle.net/u5q9a5cy/1/

Comment: @Soorapadman please see new details.

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
<style>
    li {
     list-style-type: none;
     float:left;
      width: 20%;
    }
    ul{
     position:relative;
    } 
    .to-move{
     position:absolute;
     left:0;
     width:20%
    }
    </style> 


     <ul>
        <li>
            <p>Test</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>Test</p>
            <div class="to-move">
                <p>Test2</p>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>Test</p>
        </li>
</ul>
```